# Forming SOAP header through apex class if the WSDL provided has no information regarding the header

Tags: apex, soap-api, wsdl2apex

```
  <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="SOAP-ENV">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>oneview</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">oneview123</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Here is how my header is structured in request .By default when my stub is generated from WSDL no information regarding  header in WSDL .So is there any code in apex i can start and include in my stub class and create this kind of header.

Update:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken=".../IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The WSDL has wsp and policy .Do WSDL to apex support this.Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you have the WSDL your trying to use? In some cases you can modify the generated code afterwards to add the missing bits the WSDL to Apex tool did not output.

Comment: https://www.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8a726b8a5e5f75b66b6d

Comment: @AndrewFawcett The above link is my wsdl.I could not modify anyting and get this working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard WSDL-->Apex feature does not support including any WSS or WSP headers in the outgoing SOAP request. You will need to forgo the WSDL-->Apex generated classes and instead manually construct the request SOAP message and then invoke the web service using the Apex HTTP callout classes. This thread should be helpful in showing you how to do this - http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/SOAP-Webservice-Callout-Issue-Generating-Output-Headers-Response/m-p/171411/highlight/true#M26424. Hope this helps.

Sandeep

Comment: excellent!Thanks for the reply!Awesome and thanks again!

Comment: SoapUI is an excellent tool for generating the XML you need to send.

Comment: Do you know if there exists any wrapper or other workaround instead generating the XML to send and analysing the response parsing the result?

Comment: @MartinBorthiry, I have documented my approach here: http://blog.dacology.com/callouts-from-salesforce-adding-soap-headers-for-wsse-security/

Comment: @dacology , thanks for the solution, It works perfect!

Comment: @dacology The link is not working. Can you please check and reshare? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can also modify the generated APEX class, adding a security header. That way you won't have to generate the entire xml string from scratch.

This is described in detail here: 
http://blog.dacology.com/callouts-from-salesforce-adding-soap-headers-for-wsse-security/
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018961/soap-security-in-salesforce