# Get Headers on Apex SOAP Webservice

Tags: webservices, soap

So I'm developing a soap webservice and I need to check the request Headers, I've spent the last 30 minutes searching how to do this but couldn't find an answer, is it possible to check the request headers and if so how?

Service example:

```
webservice static AccountAddressResult UpdateAccountAddressInfo(AccountAddress accountAddressInfo, String addressType, String addressCategory)
{
    //Check Headers here
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forming SOAP header through apex class if the WSDL provided has no information regarding the header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7587/forming-soap-header-through-apex-class-if-the-wsdl-provided-has-no-information-r)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, nor do I think you can actually pass in extra parameters to an Apex SOAP service without it throwing an error. Is there a reason that you expose your service as an Apex REST API? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm This will give you more flexibility and be able to inspect the HTTP headers as well