# How to add username-password authentication via SOAP header in Apex

Tags: apex, soap

I'm having problems understanding how to add authentication for a web service call. I generated the Apex classes importing wsdl.

The documentation for the WS only states that "it is recommended to use authentication via a SOAP header, assigning the provided username and password". But, no header is defined in the wsdl. Here is the stub for the soap service the wsdl generated:

```
public class BasicHttpBinding_ICfeService {
    public String endpoint_x = '';
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;
    public String clientCertPasswd_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Uruware.Ucfe.Inbox.WebService', 'UruWebService', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/', 'SerializationUruWS', 'http://www.uruware.com/ucfe/inbox/webservice', 'UruInboxWebService'};
    public UruWebService.RespBody Invoke(UruInboxWebService.ReqBody req) {
        UruInboxWebService.Invoke_element request_x = new UruInboxWebService.Invoke_element();
        request_x.req = req;
        UruInboxWebService.InvokeResponse_element response_x;
        Map<String, UruInboxWebService.InvokeResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, UruInboxWebService.InvokeResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://www.uruware.com/ucfe/inbox/webservice/ICfeService/Invoke',
          'http://www.uruware.com/ucfe/inbox/webservice',
          'Invoke',
          'http://www.uruware.com/ucfe/inbox/webservice',
          'InvokeResponse',
          'UruInboxWebService.InvokeResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.InvokeResult;
    }
}
```

**From what I read and understand:**

- The inputHttpHeaders and outputHttpHeaders have nothing to do with soap headers. Using those to send the credentials won't work.
- The clientCert properties don't work either (I tried with no success, don't know what those are)
- SOAP headers are usually defined in the wsdl file, but none are in my case

**This is the example the documentation provides for SOAP header-level authorization:**

```
<s:Header>
<o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2014-11-05T16:17:00.723Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-11-05T16:22:00.723Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-44e6951f-80b9-482c-a902-8b961406a43a-1">
        <o:Username>nombre_usuario</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">clave_usuario</o:Password>
    </o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

How can I had those headers manually? I've read some posts where it says the auto-generated stubs could be modified to include the headers I want, but I have no clue as to how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

You usually set those things in the Authorization header. I would recommend to setup  a Postman Project (Or something similar) beforehand, to understand what you really need before you start developing.

You could test setting an Authorization header like this:

```
String username = 'USERNAME';
String password = 'PASSWORD';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
inputHttpHeaders_x.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```

**Please don't hardcode Username & Password in the APEX Code**: It would be better to use Named Credentials. You can read up on it here, they also give some examples how to use it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm

Comment: Those are HttpHeaders. I need to add authentication with SOAP headers, as explained in my post.

Comment: Sorry. Here are a few Options which might help you better.

1. Ask for an WSLD (from the provider/endpoint), which includes this information. As It seems this is optional. So maybe they can give you a full WSDL, which will contain the SOAP Header information. (Not sure if Salesforce would be able to parse the WSDL then correctly)

2. Here is a gernal StackExchange article, explaining the same thing -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726127/adding-soap-implicit-headers-to-wsdl You will have to try and adopt it to APEX.

Comment: Also some more APEX Salesforce Relate Stackexchange Articles: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7587/forming-soap-header-through-apex-class-if-the-wsdl-provided-has-no-information-r
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018961/soap-security-in-salesforce
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yTdIAI
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018961/soap-security-in-salesforce
hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up switching from SOAP to REST for this integration, as authentication was much simpler and is more debug-friendly. Thanks for the resources anyway!